# Iterating Backbone Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've setup a backbone collection for `Users` and when I execute the fetch method, I get back a JSON object along the lines of: `{"users": [{...}, {...}, ...], size: number}` from the server. Confusingly, when I execute the code below, instead of getting each `user` object, I get a single "child" object, which has two **attributes**: *users* and *size*; can anyone help me understand why? Thanks.

```
display: function(){
  this.collection.each(function(user){ 
    console.log("main", user); 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a method on the collection called parse:

```
var collection = new Backbone.Collection({
   parse: function(response) {
       return response.users;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This makes perfect sense to me. Look at the JSON: it has two properties: *users* and *size.*

You probably just want to iterate over `collection.users`:

```
display: function(){
  this.collection.users.each(function(user){ 
    console.log("main", user); 
  });
}
```

Alternately, just assigned `collection` to `foo.users` instead of `foo` (where `foo` is the object created by parsing the returned JSON).